# groovy to handle soap request

Tags: grails, groovy, wsdl

i want to hit this soap request to my groovy service,

here's my soap request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fin="http://financial.sekuritas.pt.com/" xmlns:java="java:financialgateway.service.RepostInvestorAccountCIMB">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <fin:getData>
         <fin:input>
            <java:memberCode>test</java:memberCode>
            <java:fileContents>somebase64encodedtext</java:fileContents>
            <java:crc32>test</java:crc32>
            <java:urlWS>test</java:urlWS>
         </fin:input>
      </fin:getData>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

but when i tried to submit request using soap ui, this error appears

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://financial.sekuritas.pt.com/", local:"input"). Expected elements are &lt;{}memberCode&gt;,&lt;{}crc32&gt;,&lt;{}fileContents&gt;,&lt;{}urlWS&gt; </faultstring>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

in the groovy service that I created, I made it like this

```
package com.pt.sekuritas.financial

import grails.transaction.Transactional
import org.grails.cxf.utils.GrailsCxfEndpoint
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import javax.annotation.Resource
import javax.jws.WebMethod
import javax.jws.WebParam
import javax.jws.WebResult
import grails.converters.JSON

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext

import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource

import groovy.sql.Sql

import com.pt.sekuritas.backoffice.Registration


@Transactional
@GrailsCxfEndpoint(address="/ReportInvestorAccountCIMB")
class ReportInvestorAccountCIMBService {
    def grailsApplication
    def base64Decode(encodedString){
                            byte[] decoded = encodedString.decodeBase64()
                            String decode = new String(decoded)
                            return decode
                            }
    @Resource WebServiceContext context
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult()
    
    getData(@WebParam(name = 'memberCode') String memberCode,           
            @WebParam(name = 'fileContents') String fileContents,
            @WebParam(name = 'crc32') String crc32,
            @WebParam(name = 'urlWS') String urlWS

            ) {
                HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)context.getMessageContext().get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST)
                def ip = request.getRemoteAddr()
                    
                def port = request.getRemotePort()
                def host = request.getRemoteHost()
                def dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
                def dateFormatterRtbo = new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
                def sTime = new SimpleDateFormat('yyyyMMdd')
                def nowDate = new Date()
                def currentDate = dateFormatter.format(nowDate)

        
                fileContents = base64Decode(fileContents)

                def externalReference="";
                def sequenceNumber="";
                def accountNumber="";
                def currency="";
                def txnDate="";
                def openBalance="";
                def closeBalance="";

                def txnAmount="";
                def txnType="";
                def txnCode="";
                def txnDesc="";
                def accountDebit="";
                def accountCredit="";

                
            def test = new XmlParser().parseText(fileContents)
            test.each { 
            if (it.@name == 'StatLine') {
                it.'*'.'*'.each {
                    if (it.@name == 'CashVal') {
                        def cashVal = new BigDecimal(it.text())
                         txnAmount= "$cashVal" 

                    }else if (it.@name == 'TrxType') {
                        def trxType = (it.text())
                          txnType="$trxType"

                    }else if (it.@name == 'DC') {
                        def dc = (it.text())
                          txnCode="$dc" 

                    }else if (it.@name == 'Description1') {
                        def description1 = (it.text())
                         txnDesc="$description1" 
                    }
                }
            }
            }

            def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(fileContents)
                xml.each {
                if(it.@name == 'ExtRef') {
                 def a = (it.text())
                 externalReference="$a"
                }else if(it.@name == 'SeqNum') {
                def b = new BigDecimal(it.text())
                 sequenceNumber="$b"
                } else if(it.@name == 'AC') {
                  def c = new BigDecimal(it.text())
                  accountNumber="$c"
                } else if(it.@name == 'CurCod') {
                 def d = (it.text())
                  currency="$d"
                } else if(it.@name == 'ValDate') {
                 def e = new BigDecimal(it.text())
                  txnDate="$e"
                } else if(it.@name == 'OpenBal') {
                def f = new BigDecimal(it.text())
                 openBalance="$f"
                } else if(it.@name == 'CloseBal') {
                def g = new BigDecimal(it.text())
                 closeBalance="$g"
                }
            }

                println("txnDate? "+txnDate)    
                
                log.info ('[ReportInvestorAccountCIMBService][ip:' + ip + '][current date:' + currentDate + '][data[externalReference:' + externalReference + ', sequenceNumber:' + sequenceNumber + ', accountNumber:' + accountNumber + ', currency:' + currency + ', txnDate:' + txnDate + ', txnType:' + ', txnCode:' + txnCode + ', accountDebit:' + accountDebit + ', accountCredit:' + accountCredit + ', txnAmount:' + txnAmount + ', openBalance:' + openBalance + ', closeBalance:' + closeBalance + ', txnDesc:' + txnDesc + ']]')
        
                def status = 1
                def processDinamis = 0
                def processRtbo = 0

                

                
                if(txnDate == ''){
                    log.error ('[ReportInvestorAccountCIMBService][ip:' + ip + '][TxnDate: is null]')
                    return status = 3       
                }
                def financialConfiguration = FinancialGatewayConfiguration.findByIpAddress(ip)
                
                        
                if(financialConfiguration) {
                    try
                    {
                        def p_txnDate = sTime.parse(txnDate)
                        def financialInstance = FinancialGatewayNotification.findByExternalReference(externalReference)
                        
                        if(financialInstance)
                        {
                            log.error ('[ReportInvestorAccountCIMBService][is exist externalReference:' + externalReference + ']')
                            return status = 4   
                        }else {
                            
                            if(txnCode == 'C'){
                                
                                accountCredit = accountNumber
                                
                            }else if(txnCode == 'D'){
                                
                                accountDebit = accountNumber
                                
                            }

                            financialInstance = new FinancialGatewayNotification()
                            financialInstance.externalReference = externalReference
                            financialInstance.sequenceNumber = sequenceNumber
                            financialInstance.accountNumber = accountNumber
                            financialInstance.currency = currency
                            financialInstance.txnDate = dateFormatter.format(p_txnDate)
                            financialInstance.txnType = txnType
                            financialInstance.txnCode = txnCode 
                            financialInstance.accountDebit = accountDebit     
                            financialInstance.accountCredit = accountCredit
                            financialInstance.txnAmount = txnAmount
                            financialInstance.openBalance = openBalance
                            financialInstance.closeBalance = closeBalance
                            financialInstance.txnDescription = txnDesc
                            financialInstance.ipAddress = financialConfiguration.ipAddress
                            financialInstance.sourceBank = financialConfiguration.sourceBank
                            
                        
                            if (financialInstance.hasErrors()) {                    
                                return status
                            }
                            financialInstance.save flush: true, failOnError: true
                            
                            def currDate = sTime.format(nowDate).toString()
                            def _txnDate = sTime.format(p_txnDate).toString()
                            
                            
                            //if(_txnDate == currDate) {
                                try
                                {
                                    log.info('[ReportInvestorAccountCIMBService]SQL SERVER: ' + grailsApplication.config.dinamis.gateway.db.url)
                                    def sql = Sql.newInstance( grailsApplication.config.dinamis.gateway.db.url,
                                                               grailsApplication.config.dinamis.gateway.db.user,
                                                               grailsApplication.config.dinamis.gateway.db.password,
                                                               grailsApplication.config.dinamis.gateway.db.driver )
                                    sql.execute('INSERT INTO CIMB_H2H (EXTERNAL_REFERENCE, SEQ_NUMBER, ACCOUNT_NUMBER, CURRENCY, TXN_DATE, TXN_TYPE, TXN_CODE, ACCOUNT_DEBIT, ACCOUNT_CREDIT, TXN_AMOUNT, OPEN_BALANCE, CLOSE_BALANCE, TXN_DESC, INSERT_TIME, MEMBER_CODE, CRC32, URL_WS) VALUES(\'' + externalReference + '\', \'' + sequenceNumber + '\', \'' + accountNumber + '\', \'' + currency + '\', \'' + dateFormatter.format(p_txnDate) + '\', \'' + txnType + '\', \'' + txnCode + '\', \'' + accountDebit + '\', \'' + accountCredit + '\', \'' + txnAmount + '\', \'' + openBalance + '\', \'' + closeBalance + '\', \'' + txnDesc + '\', \'' +  currentDate + '\', \'' +  memberCode + '\',  \'' +  crc32 + '\',  \'' +  urlWS + '\')')
                                    processDinamis = 1
                                    sql.close()
                                    
                                }
                                catch(Exception exc)
                                {
                                    log.error ('[ReportInvestorAccountCIMBService][ip:' + ip + '][error: SQL EXECUTE')
                                    processDinamis = 0 
                                    exc.printStackTrace()
                                }
                            /*
                            }else {
                                log.info('[ReportInvestorAccountCIMBService][ip:' + ip + '][current date:' + currentDate + '][data[externalReference:' + externalReference + ', sequenceNumber:' + sequenceNumber + ', accountNumber:' + accountNumber + ', currency:' + currency + ', txnDate:' + txnDate + ', txnType:' + ', txnCode:' + txnCode + ', accountDebit:' + accountDebit + ', accountCredit:' + accountCredit + ', txnAmount:' + txnAmount + ', openBalance:' + openBalance + ', closeBalance:' + closeBalance + ', txnDesc:' + txnDesc + ']]The ' + currDate + ' not match with _txnDate ' + _txnDate)
                            }*/
                                financialInstance.processResponse = processDinamis
                                financialInstance.processDate = currentDate
                                
                                financialInstance.save flush: true, failOnError: true
                                
                                // S21 RTBO
                                if(accountNumber) {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        log.info('[ReportInvestorAccountCIMBService]SQL SERVER: ' + grailsApplication.config.rtbo.gateway.db.url)
                                        def sql = Sql.newInstance( grailsApplication.config.rtbo.gateway.db.url,
                                                                   grailsApplication.config.rtbo.gateway.db.user,
                                                                   grailsApplication.config.rtbo.gateway.db.password,
                                                                   grailsApplication.config.rtbo.gateway.db.driver )
                                        
                                        sql.execute('EXEC RtboAddFundinout \'' + dateFormatterRtbo.format(p_txnDate) + '\', \'' + currentDate + '\', \'' + txnDesc + '\', null, \'' + accountNumber + '\', \'' + txnAmount + '\', \'' + openBalance + '\', \'' + txnCode + '\', \'' + txnType + '\', \'' + 'H2H' + '\', \'' + '' + '\', \'' + accountDebit + '\', \'' + accountCredit + '\', \'' + externalReference + '\', \'' + 'Cimb' + '\'')
                                        processRtbo = 1
                                        sql.close()
                                        
                                    }
                                    catch(Exception exc)
                                    {
                                        log.error ('[ReportInvestorAccountCIMBService][ip:' + ip + '][error: SQL EXECUTE')
                                        processRtbo = 0
                                        exc.printStackTrace()
                                    }
                                    
                                    financialInstance.processResponse = processRtbo
                                    financialInstance.processDate = currentDate
                                    
                                    financialInstance.save flush: true, failOnError: true
                                    
                                }else {
                                    log.info ('[ReportInvestorAccountCIMBService][ip:' + ip + ']Empty Account Number')
                                }
                                
                                try {
                                    if(txnType == '61' && txnDesc == 'PHINTRACO PHINTRACO' && txnAmount == '50000.0000') {
                                        def c = com.pt.sekuritas.backoffice.Registration.createCriteria()
                                        def d = c.list{
                                            eq('rdn', accountNumber)
                                            eq('rdnBank', 'Cimb')
                                            isNotNull('onlineRegistration')
                                        }
                                        
                                        if(d.size() > 0) {
                                            def registrationInstance = d[0]
                                            def cal = Calendar.getInstance()
                                            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2021)
                                            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 9)
                                            cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1)
                                            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0)
                                            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
                                            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
                                            def startDate = cal.time
                                            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2022)
                                            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0)
                                            cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1)
                                            def endDate = cal.time
                                            log.info('[ReportInvestorAccountCIMBService][txnType:' + txnType + '][txnDesc:' + txnDesc + '][accountNumber:' + accountNumber + '][onlineRegistration.dateCreated:' + registrationInstance.onlineRegistration.dateCreated + '][startDate:' + startDate + '][endDate:' + endDate + ']')
                                            
                                            if(registrationInstance.onlineRegistration.dateCreated > startDate && registrationInstance.onlineRegistration.dateCreated < endDate) {
                                                //PROMO DIMODALIN
                                                def accountInstance = registrationInstance.onlineRegistration.account
                                                Long longDepositAmount = Float.parseFloat(txnAmount)
                                                java.text.NumberFormat deFormat = java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(new java.util.Locale("de", "DE"))
                                                def formattedAmount = deFormat.format(longDepositAmount)
                                                        
                                                def username = registrationInstance.username
                                                def name = registrationInstance.name
                                                
                                                def message = '<h2>Yeay!</h2><br/><b>' + name + '</b> Kamu dapat modal Rp' + formattedAmount + ' dari Phintraco Sekuritas.<br/>Cek saldo RDN kamu sekarang ya.<br/>Segera beli saham pilihan kamu.<br/>Ayo tingkatkan investasi kamu dengan top up saldo RDN kamu dan beli saham lebih banyak lagi.<br/>' + 
                                                              'Salam Profits<br/><b>#bukarekeningdimodalin</b>'
                                                
                                                def pushData = ['channel': 'PTANYWHERE_TRANSACTION_NOTIFICATION',
                                                                  'type':'cashDeposit',
                                                                  'subType':'',
                                                                  'sender':'financialGateway',
                                                                  'recipient': accountInstance.username,
                                                                  'priority':'0',
                                                                  'isHtml':'true',
                                                                  'sentTime': System.currentTimeMillis(),
                                                                  'title':'Promo Buka Rekening Dimodalin',
                                                                  'body':message,
                                                                  'ticker':message,
                                                                  'targetIntent':'',
                                                                  'additionalData1':'',
                                                                  'additionalData2':'',
                                                                  'additionalData3':'',
                                                                  'additionalData4':'',
                                                                  'additionalData5':'',
                                                                 ]
                                                def fcmMessage = (pushData as JSON).toString()
                                                log.info('[ReportInvestorAccountCIMBService][txnType:' + txnType + '][txnDesc:' + txnDesc + '][accountNumber:' + accountNumber + '][username:' + username + '][name:' + name + '][onlineRegistration.dateCreated:' + registrationInstance.onlineRegistration.dateCreated + '][message:' + message + '][fcmMessage:' + fcmMessage + ']')
                                                
                                                com.pt.sekuritas.util.ActiveMQHolder.getInstance().pushNotification(fcmMessage)
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                catch(Exception exc) {
                                    log.error ('[ReportInvestorAccountCIMBService][ip:' + ip + '][error: FAILED PROCESSING NOTIFICATION]')
                                    exc.printStackTrace()
                                }
                                
                                return status = 1
                        }
                        
                    }
                    catch(Exception exc)
                    {
                        log.error ('[ReportInvestorAccountCIMBService][ip:' + ip + '][error: FAILED INSERT]')
                        exc.printStackTrace()
                        return status = 0
                    }
                }else {
                    log.error('[ReportInvestorAccountCIMBService]not found ip address: ' + ip)
                    return status = 2
                }
                
    }
}
```

how can I send a request with a wsdl like that?
what should i change from my groovy service source code
in order to comply with the wsdl above?

Comment: https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html

Comment: Hi @daggett , thank you for helping me, i already updated my question and attach full source code of my groovy service

Comment: so, the error is pretty clear `fin:input` not expected at place where you are using it. and let me correct you:  instead of `wsdl request` you should use `soap request`. `wsdl = web service definition language` -  is a document that describes soap service.

Comment: So you can tell me what must i change from my service, to be able to use input tags @dagget?

Comment: the error means that your request is incorrect. input requirements defined by a service provider and by wsdl file. if you have wsdl file the tool like SoapUI could generate for you correct request body.